# How to prevent dnsmasq from creating AAAA records for hosts using DHCPv6?

Tags: dns, dhcp, ipv6, dnsmasq

I have a dual stack (V4+V6) internal network with dnsmasq providing DNS, DHCP, and DHCPv6 services. I want to use ipv4 for most of my internal host to host communications, so I don't want dnsmasq to publish AAAA records since it's generally preferred by many TCP/IP implementations.

At the moment, dnsmasq generates an A record from the hostname once it gives an IPv4 address via DHCP (which is OK), and an AAAA record for IPv6 addresses given via DHCPv6 (which I want to avoid).

I have a long dnsmasq configuration, but the relevant sections are:

```
# Add local domain and expand
local=/lan/
domain=lan
expand-hosts

# Enable RADV
enable-ra

# DHCP range for v4
dhcp-range=set:internal,172.10.1.100,172.10.1.199,255.255.255.0,24h

# DHCP range for v6
dhcp-range=::100,::999,constructor:lan1.4

# One of my fixed hosts
dhcp-host=<mac_address_redacted>,172.10.1.250,24h # triton
```

Interface lan1.4 has the proper ipv4 and ipv6 addresses on the DNS/DHCP server and the all internal hosts are getting proper v4 and v6 ips. But, once I get an address, for instance for host `triton`, I get the following DNS records added by dnsmasq:

```
triton.lan has address <redacted>            <-- I want this
triton.lan has IPv6 address <redacted>       <-- I don't want this
```

(I've replaced the real addresses by `<redacted>` above).

I've done all sorts of modifications to the `dhcp-range` directive for ipv6, without success. I don't use the `ra-names` mode in the `dhcp-range` line, so I didn't expect dnsmasq to generate AAAA names. The dnsmasq manpage says:

> ra-names  enables  a  mode  which gives DNS names to dual-stack hosts which do SLAAC for IPv6. Dnsmasq uses the host's IPv4 lease to derive the name, network segment and MAC address and  assumes  that  the host will also have an IPv6 address calculated using the SLAAC algorithm, on the same network segment. The address is pinged, and if a reply is received, an AAAA record is added to the DNS  for  this  IPv6 address. Note that this is only happens for directly-connected networks, (not one doing DHCP via a relay) and it will not work if a host is using privacy extensions. ra-names can be combined with  ra-stateless and slaac.

I don't understand why the AAAA names are being added and how to prevent that from happening.

I've considered blacking out AAAA records completely, but that would also prevent my internal ipv6 hosts from using ipv6 hosts on the Internet (they all use the same internal DNS server, which then forwards external queries to 1.1.1.1).

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why? Who cares if it is IPv6 or IPv4.